# Boost asio and thread, if i run two instances i get cpu at 100%

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I created a console application that sends data on a network link. I used the boost library, both the thread and the asio ones; currently i'm running it under Windows. If I run a single application it works perfectly, but if I open two instances on two different consoles, the CPU load goes to 100%, if I close one of the application it goes back to normal. I just used a simple socket with async reads and writes, and threads with condition variables and mutexes. Is there any special thingh to do when dealing with such a situation? I can show you some code, but I think it's nothing special:

```
socket->connect(tcp::endpoint(address::from_string(getAddress()),getPort()));
```

for connecting

and

```
socket->async_read_some(buffer(receiveData),bind(&NetworkLink::handle_response, this,placeholders::error,placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

inside the handle_response function for async reading.
For the thread I use

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> messages_lock(message_received_mutex);
```

Before deleting everything and starting a simple test project from scratch I would like to know if there are any special care to be taken in this situation.

Comment: So, you want all that processing power that you paid for to go to waste? Please explain why you believe this behaviour is not correct/desired.

Comment: please post complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you recheck by using "async_read" instead of "async_read_some".Its just my gut feeling. Need more/complete code to understand

Comment: @r-martinho-fernandes why should I want to have the CPU always at 100% when the software does nothing? My code is spread on many classes, I will try to make a simple example and post it. Thanks
PS: as I said, it happens only when I run two instances of the program, with just one it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems I've tracked down the problem. First of all, the 100% CPU usage was due to the fact that each instance was using 50% of the CPU (I'm on a dual core PC). So I run all over the code and found out this. I had this in my code, inside the NetworkLink::handle_response function:

```
socket->async_read_some(
    boost::asio::buffer(receiveData),
    boost::bind(&NetworkLink::handle_response, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
io_service.run();
```

I used the io_service.run(); because before the software was not receiving data. Now I removed the line, I don't get the 50% CPU usage, but the handler response is not called so I cannot receive any data. Any thought about this?
Thanks

PS: I created a small app that shows this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
#include "boost/thread/mutex.hpp"

#ifdef _WIN32
#include "Windows.h"
#endif

using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace std;

std::vector<uint8_t> buf;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket mysocket(io_service);

int handle_response(const boost::system::error_code &err,
        size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    // cout << bytes_transferred << ' ';
    if (bytes_transferred > 0)
        cout << buf.data() << ' ';
    boost::asio::async_read(mysocket, boost::asio::buffer(buf),
            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), &handle_response);
}

int mythread()
{
    boost::asio::async_read(mysocket, boost::asio::buffer(buf),
            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), &handle_response);

    io_service.run();
}

int main()
{
    int m_nPort = 12345;

    buf.resize(100, '0');
    boost::condition_variable message_received_condition;
    boost::thread message_receiver_thread(&mythread);
    boost::mutex messages_mutex;

    tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"),
            m_nPort);

    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> messages_lock(messages_mutex);
    message_received_condition.notify_one();

    cout << "Waiting for connection..." << endl;

    Sleep(10000);
    mysocket.connect(endpoint);
    cout << "connection accepted" << endl;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            boost::asio::socket_base::bytes_readable command(true);
            mysocket.io_control(command);
            std::size_t bytes_readable = command.get();

            mysocket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf),
                    &handle_response);

            io_service.run();
        }
    } catch (exception &e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl; //"The parameter is incorrect" exception
    }
}
```

If you remove the comment from th line 
        // cout << bytes_transferred << ' '; 
in the handle response functionyou get a lower CPU usage, I guess because of the delay for writing to the screen.

Comment: It seems that the  boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1) is not working, since the handler is called also when no data has been received (i.e. bytes_transferred == 0), is it a normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the error. If there is a failure, you continue to read anyway, which will probably immediately post back a completion with a failure, ad infinitum.

Comment: I changed the code and added a sleep of 1 ms if nothing was read, I get a very low CPU load, is that what you meant?